# Change Aspect Ratio of Video in Python

Tags: python, video, edit

I have a video in 16:9 that I would like to be in 9:16. I have tried to use python libraries such as cv2, ffmpeg or MoviePy but some of them did it without the sound and others just compressed the whole video (it did not crop the left and right sides it just made the picture messy).

Is there a way to change the change the aspect ratio while zooming in so that the new video fills out the whole canvas? And of course while keeping the audio in python?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem to you and came up with the following solution using Moviepy. Moviepy will keep the sound.

I'm going to assume your 16:9 videos are 1920w by 1080h and you don't want to resize / compress your video.
This means the maximum dimensions for your new 9:16 video can be 607.5w by 1080h.

607.5 / 1080 = 0.5625 = 9:16

You can't have half a px (607.5) for your new video's width, therefor to keep the ratio of 9:16 the next best dimensions are 576w by 1024h (correct me if I'm wrong).

You can then crop the original video clip with those dimensions.

Here's an example of what it might look like in code:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx
    
# Create a temp video clip for this example
temp_clip = mp.ColorClip(size=(1920, 1080), color=(0, 0, 255), duration=1)
temp_clip.write_videofile("blue_original_clip.mp4", fps=30) 

# This is where you load in your original clip    
clip_16_9 = mp.VideoFileClip("blue_original_clip.mp4")
    
# Now lets crop out a 9:16 section from the original
# x1=0, y1=0 will take the section from the top left corner
clip_9_16 = vfx.crop(clip_16_9, x1=0, y1=0, width=576, height=1024)
clip_9_16.write_videofile("new_clip.mp4")
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

well try this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:/New folder/video.avi')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 5, (1280,720))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        b = cv2.resize(frame,(1280,720),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        out.write(b)
    else:
        break
    
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: OP specifically said that OpenCV was unsuitable because it does not support audio